# A nice library to do real-time gaming

Tags: real-time, game-engine

I'm starting a development to support real-time gaming. I need to support collaborative game in adventure mode and each-against-all mode. The game is being develop on the Ogre engine.

So, please, I need to know a library/framework to do this.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [RakNet engine](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/). It is feature rich well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what you actually mean, but I suspect you mean you want multiple players over the internet.  I suggest you take a look at [RakNet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Another cloud based service that I have heard about, but not yet used, is Photon Network Engine.

http://www.exitgames.com/